# Is there a way to use functions defined in a library in any class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to design a menu interface on a 1.8'' TFT display module. I've got it working with the Adafruit_ST7735 + Adafruit_GFX libraries. At least when I was just trying out the features... But now I'm trying to organize the code in Classes as this thing will get too complex soon. I have done some Java and C, so I started learning C++. I've been reading and coding nonstop for a week now, but there are some things that I can't wrap my head around that keep me from making any progress for a couple of days already.

So... For example there's a function public void drawRect(); in Adafruit_ST7735 library and I have a function draw() that draws a bunch of related stuff to the display in my own class (Rectangle.cpp). Say I initialize the display in my main program file how can I use that drawRect() function in my Rectangle::draw()?

Also Rectangle will be used for composing other parts of the menu interface and will probably be initialized in a collection or as a member of another class.

I've tried a bunch of different things but I've come to a dead end.

EDIT:

main program:

```
#include "_v0_0_0.h"
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include <SPI.h>

#include "Point.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "SomeView.h"

#define     TFT_CS  4
#define     TFT_RST 0
#define     TFT_DC  10

Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
SomeView a_view;

void setup()
{
    tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB); // initializes the display
}

void loop()
{
    a_view.draw(); //draw something to view (a button, scrollbar, menu item, etc)
    while (true) {}
}
```

SomeView.h:

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

class SomeView {
private:
    Rectangle a_rectangle;
public:
    SomeView();
    void draw();

    const Rectangle& getRectangle() const {
        return a_rectangle;
    }

    void setRectangle(const Rectangle& rectangle) {
        a_rectangle = rectangle;
    }
};
```

SomeView.cpp:

```
#include "SomeView.h"

SomeView::SomeView() :
        a_rectangle(Point::Point(0, 0), Point::Point(0, 0)) {
}

void SomeView::draw() {
    a_rectangle.setCorners(Point::Point(0, 0), Point::Point(2, 6));
    a_rectangle.draw();

    a_rectangle.setCorners(Point::Point(20, 66), Point::Point(100, 100));
    a_rectangle.draw();
}
```

Rectangle.h:

```
#include "Point.h"
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include <SPI.h>

class Rectangle{
private:
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(Point& p1, Point& p2);
    void setCorners(const Point& p1, const Point& p2);
    void draw();

    // ... getters and setters for the points
};
```

Rectangle.cpp:

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

Rectangle::Rectangle() : p1(), p2()
    {
    }

Rectangle::Rectangle(Point& p1, Point& p2) : p1(p1), p2(p2)
    {
    }

void Rectangle::setCorners(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
    this->p1 = p1;
    this->p2 = p2;
}

// this is where I want to use a function from the adafruit library
void Rectangle::draw() {
    Adafruit_ST7735::drawRect(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY(), ST7735_GREEN); 

}
```

Comment: So are you asking how to pass the tft to a class after creating this object ?.... Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS,  TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic methods to do what you want:

1. Inheritance
2. Pointer passing

Inheritance involves making your new class a *child* class of the Adafruit TFT class.  You new class then gets all the public functions of the Adafruit class - it essentially becomes the Adafruit class *plus* your extra functions overlaid over the top:

```
class Rectangle : public Adafruit_ST7735 {
    ...
};
```

You have to ensure that you provide a suitable constructor that passes the right parameters to the Adafruit parent class, and then you create a Rectangle class *instead* of the Adafruit class in your sketch.

- Inheritance tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

That is fine if you just want one class that uses the functions from the Adafruit class.  The second option is to pass a pointer (or reference) to the Adafruit class to your other classes, either when you construct them or at function call time.  For instance, you might have:

```
class Rectangle {
    private:
        Adafruit_ST7735 *_tft;

    public:
        Rectangle(Adafruit_ST7735 &tft) : _tft(&tft) {}
};
```

Then in your function you can use:

```
void Rectangle::draw() {
    _tft->drawRect(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY(), ST7735_GREEN);
}
```

You would, of course, construct your class with:

```
Adafruit_ST7735 myTFTScreen(blah blah blah);
Rectangle myRect(myTFTScreen);
```

Then call `myRect.draw();`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

However that's not how object oriented programming (OOP) is supposed to be used, at least in theory.

Most likely you won't like my advice, but here it is: take it easy, find a good book or online course and learn to program on a system that is simpler to debug, than a microcontroller.

Your PC, for example.

C is closer to the HW than java. C++ can be seen as both of them, but there is not so much you can do without learning C, properly.
From that perspective, C++ can be seen also as a superset of C, only much more complex.

Have a look at [this explanation](http://karwin.blogspot.fi/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html), for example.
It's quite simple, but exhaustive. Read it carefully and you will find out that pointers are not so difficult to grasp, after all.

If you spend enough time to get the basics right, it will save you lots of frustration (and, yes, time!) later on.

For a more systematic approach, try [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Though this was the kind of answer I was afraid I'm going to get. It's not that I'm not willing to learn. I've read most of the material on [link]http://www.learncpp.com/ but it's like with learning... a new language :D In the beginning you start to grasp the meaning of single words or expressions but it's hard to form a meaningful text - there will be lots of grammar mistakes and cases of misused words. So I understand what you we're saying but you're also suggesting that I should put this project aside. That won't happen.

Comment: Sure, it's your time after all and a lesson is not fully learned till one has paid the price for it. But you know the saying: the wise man learns from own mistakes, while the smart one learns from others'  ;-)

Comment: More to the point of the question you asked: you got my answer because you question is too generic and doesn't show exactly what you are trying to do, why, how and what error you get. Lacking that, you get the rubber stamp answer.

Comment: I thought my question was descriptive enough (though a bit emotional while still trying the best to express myself) but I didn't provide any concrete examples of what I have been doing because my last experiments have become so desperate and ridiculous that these won't have any descriptive value to my problem. I tried to keep it generic also to strip away details which I thought of as being trivial. Also I feel like none of your answers have been more on point than my question.

Comment: Indeed. That's what you get for not being clear/precise enough.
How do you think that the answer could be more precise than the question? If I had a working crystal ball, I'd be hitting a different type of website. The type specialized in trading stocks.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what was not so clear in my question. I don't own a crystal ball either :D I'm not writing this in my fist language and I'm asking about a programming language that I'm still new to. I'm really OK with providing more info, but I'm not OK with noob-shaming or degrading attitude towards someone who is willing to learn, but needs a little push.

Comment: I don't see what noob shaming there is in my answer. It's a heartfelt advice about how to optimize your progress.
Btw, you already got an answer by OP but, as expected, it was not what you wanted. If you only would post the code you are trying to run, even as an example, as long as it represents what you really want to do, it would be possible to have a concrete discussion. Without that, it will be just frustration from both ends.

Comment: I don't think Igor's answer was noob-shaming or degrading at all. I looked at your question and couldn't really see what you were asking. You said `I've tried a bunch of different things but I've come to a dead end.` - is the problem a compile error? If so, what is it? Is it compiling but not working? Your topic is `Is there a way to use functions defined in a library in any class?` - well, yes there is a way. Otherwise there wouldn't be much point in having libraries, if they couldn't be used anywhere. Can you post a more specific question?